# Wildcard Regex inside literal

Tags: regex

I have a XML formatted response that I need to Regex out (using Splunk) there are a number of variance tags like to account for they look similar to this:

```
<charge-request>
...
</charge-request
```

and

```
<charge-response>
...
</charge-response>
```

However, the `<charge` portion can be replaced by a number of different things depending on what the system is doing, (i.e. Charging, refunding, etc) id like to figure out how I can wild card it something like `<*-request>` to not care about what is between the `<` and the ending of `-request>`, the `<*-request>` also needs to be part of the group since its part of the original request/response.

Right now I have a regex such as this:

```
"(?<raw_message>(?:<charge-request>|<charge-response>).*(?:<\/charge-request>|<\/charge-response>))"
```

How can I update this to not care about what is in  the `<` and the ending of `-request>` (or `-response>` for that matter)

Comment: To parse XML, please use an XML parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/w matches a single word character, /w+ matches a string of word charcters up to some other kind of character.  So:

```
(<\w+)(-)(request>|response>)
```

should match

```
<anyword-request> and <anyword-response>.
```

While:

```
(<\w+)(-)(\w+>)
```

should match

```
<anyword-anyword>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a proper [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) parser: [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint):

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[starts-with(name(), "charge")]' file
```

This will match all tags beginnings with `charge`.

Example to retrieve the content of these tags:

```
$ cat file.xml
<root>
  <charge-request>
  foo
  </charge-request>
  <charge-response>
  bar
  </charge-response>
  <charge-any>
  base
  </charge-any>
  <anything>
  xxx
  </anything>
</root>
```

then

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[starts-with(name(), "charge")]/text()' file
```

### Output

```
foo

bar

base
```